# What is the solution when owner.transfer(msg.value) function becomes fail?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

```
contract A {
  function sendtoken() payable returns(bool) {
      require(msg.value!=0);
      balances[msg.sender]+= 1;
      balances[owner]-= 1;
      owner.transfer(msg.value);
      return true;
  }
}
```

Here if the `owner.transfer(msg.value)` function fails, then the token will definitely send to the sender, but the ether will not get to the owner. How can prevent this error? Is calling the function `owner.transfer(msg.value)` before the token transfer a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<address>.transfer` will automatically throw, or in other words, trigger `revert`ion of all state changes, and the tokens will not transfer.

Comment: So if the transfer fails then all the state changes that I made with this payable function will revert to its previous state? There are no worries about this?

Comment: Yes, any changes made within that call will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

`.transfer()` will throw error. If user don't have enough funds. Use revert it will revert back the changes to previous changes.

Or try below method.

```
contract A {
function sendtoken() payable returns(bool) {
      require(msg.value!=0);
      owner.transfer(msg.value);
      balances[msg.sender]+= 1;
      balances[owner]-= 1;
      return true;
 }
}
```

Or another way

```
contract A {
function sendtoken() payable returns(bool) {
      require(msg.value!=0);
      require(owner.send(msg.value));
      balances[msg.sender]+= 1;
      balances[owner]-= 1;
      return true;
 }
}
```

Roll back my code to fix race conditions. For more details refer below link
https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/

Comment: Careful with this, in both example of the receiving address is a contract, it could trigger code execution thereby allowing possible exploitation of the contract implementing this. You should *ALWAYS* do your accounting first.

Comment: There will be a issue as race condition qus. So I am modifying the same. check below link https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/